# How do I make the math come out correctly using `size_t` numbers? Or what’s a better way than `max_size()` to get the range of a `vector`/`string`?

Tags: c++, c++17

I’m trying to get an idea of the exact number of bits (if possible) or bytes and the range of numbers the various data types could (if manipulated to do so) have on the compiler I’m using (onlinegdb). I tried to make my own, but I’m having an issue doing math in the compiler with `size_t` numbers. So far I’ve added to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cwchar>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

Getting an output like:

```
         Char: 1 bytes
        Range: -128 - 127

Unsigned Char: 1 bytes
        Range: 0 - 255
```

et cetera: `wchar_t`, `string`, `bitset<1>`, `bool`, `short`, `int`, `wint_t`, `long`, `long long`, `size_t`, `float`, `double`, `long double`, `mbstate_t`, as well as their unsigned (when existing) and vector versions of all. It works until I got to calculating the range of the `string` and `vector`s. In order to calculate the number range of a `string` or `vector` I figured I could simply multiply the range of the type by the number of them my `string`/`vector` could hold (found using its `max_size()` function). However the math doesn’t work. (Edit §1)

The massive number produced by `max_size()` of a `vector<char>` (18446744073709551615) multiplied by the `CHAR_MIN` (-128) results in `128`. Looks like it’s just `CHAR_MIN` multiplying by -1… So I investigated. (Edit §2.1)

I added `#include <typeinfo>` to check if the data types were mismatched, and they were: `size_t` from the function and `int` from the macro constants. Converting the `size_t` number to `int` just gets `-1`. So I guess that’s the problem. (Edit §2.2)

So I tried converting the `int` of `CHAR_MIN` to `size_t`, but that got me `18446744073709551488`. Which multiplied by the function output still gets `128`… A calculator is showing me the correct answer is around -2.3611832414*10^(21). I don’t know for sure what I’m doing wrong (rollover from max-reached?), but if there’s some header I can include that gives me a function that’ll do it for me that’d help too. (Edit §2.3)

Edit:

§1:

§1.1: Since user 463035818_is_not_a_number seems to think this wasn’t included:

This is where I defined “range.” In the second to last sentence of the paragraph following the output. The text there is identical to how it was in the first published draft.

§1.2: Since user Nathan Pierson assumed I’m saving the mathematic result to a variable:

“Output” refers to using an `ostream` like `cout` to display something on the console. I didn’t mention anything about storing the number because there is no need to save it to any variable. I’m not sure why a size limitation would be implemented for an output, but if it somehow is then it just circles back to the question I asked in the title.

§2: Since user 463035818_is_not_a_number said it wasn’t clear enough:

(I’m assuming you don’t need the `cout` part of the code.)

§2.1:
The word “multiplied” means using the `*` operator between 2 numbers:

```
vectorCharVariable.max_size() * CHAR_MIN
```

§2.2:
This is how you use `#include <typeinfo>` (a standard C++ header I assumed everyone answering would be familiar with) to get the name of the type:

With `#include <vector>`s data type function:

```
typeid(vectorCharVariable.max_size()).name()
```

With `#include <climits>` macro constant:

```
typeid(CHAR_MIN).name()
```

§2.3:
This is how you use type casting (a fundamental feature of C++ requiring no included header that I assumed everyone answering would be familiar with) to change the type of a variable:

Using *functional* syntax on the `vector` function’s output variable to make it `int` instead of `size_t` resulting in `-1`:

```
int(vectorCharVariable.max_size())
```

Using *functional* syntax on the macro constant’s output variable to make it `size_t` instead of `int` and multiplying it by the max size of the `vector` resulting in `128`:

```
c.max_size() * size_t(CHAR_MIN)
```

Furthermore, the math is also wrong when interpreting the maximum:

```
c.max_size() * size_t(CHAR_MAX)
```

The expected result of `18446744073709551615 * 127` is 2.3427365e+21, not `18446744073709551489`. Clearly the issue is the compiler reading the number in `size_t` (which is unsigned 64 bit) as signed 64 bit using TCP in the binary to decimal which make `c.max_size()` (64 1’s in binary) `-1` and `-1 * 127` is `-127` (which is `18446744073709551489` in unsigned 64 bit). Thus the solution to my question would be how to make it stop interpreting the `size_t` numbers as signed in mathematical calculations.

§3: Since it wasn’t clear to user Daniel Langr:

Between the range of a data type and the number of combinations (“distinct values” as you call them) of a datatype I am trying to get the former (the range). Range is limited below the maximum number of combinations by the separation of variables. It is impossible to store the number 65536 in an array of 2 ‘char’s, one can only store at most the number 127 twice (127*2=254).

The number’s stored are at most 127 `n` number of times, where `n` is the maximum number of `char` variables in it. Maybe you’re thinking about how one could use a function or `class` to reinterpret the data, but the result of reinterpretations is not the number stored on the `vector`. If that’s the case you’re assuming extra steps that were not listed because they don’t exist.

Comment: please clarify, what is "range of a `string` or `vector`" ?

Comment: Is [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) of any use to you?

Comment: The fact that the result would be negative for an odd number of max vector elements and positive for an even number of max vector elements raises some alarm bells that it's not whatever calculation you intended to make.

Comment: the question is difficult to understand, because you are discussing output of some code you don't show (and its not clear what is the relevance of those includes) Please read about [mcve]

Comment: It looks like `max_size()` there is in fact one less than the maximum possible `size_t`. You're going to need an even larger integral type to represent values larger than than that if you want to multiply it by something like -128.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The lowest and highest number possibly represented (in the set), as with individual data types. I was thinking that’d be the sum of the parts, although I could be wrong. Example: `char` has a range of -128 to 127 on my compiler, so a `char array[2]` would have a range of -256 to 254 (`array[0]+array[1]`), and a `string` would be -128 times the maximum number of `char`s a `string` can hold with a specific compiler on a specific system.

Comment: if that is your definition you should include it in the question. Frankly, I don't think it is very useful, because with your notion of "range" the range of any array is out of the range of values of its elements

Comment: `char` representation has (usually) 8 bits, therefore, it can represent 2^8=256 distinct values. Such as -128 to 127 if `char` is unsigned. Array of 2 `char`s has 16 bits, which are generally able to represent 2^16=65536 distinct values. This is much much more than your -256 to 254. BTW I still don't understand your question. Maybe you should focus on a single problem/question only.

Comment: Trying to calculate the maximum possible "range" for something like `string` or `vector` is going to be a pretty worthless result. There are almost always practical issues at runtime that would prevent one from creating extremely large strings or vectors (such as address space issues in 32bit or the computer's limit of RAM in 64bit).

Comment: A `size_t` is just not enough to represent the numbers you are trying to calculate. You can try a 128-bit wide integral type, if it's provided by your environment or just use a `double`, if you don't need the exact value.

Comment: With that definition, multiplying by -128 is indeed fishy. What you're actually looking for is a much, much higher number: `2^(8*max_size())` possible values centred around 0. That number has somewhere in the range of ~10^19 _digits_. (Each bit has 2 values, and there are `8*max_size()` bits to play with.)